# How can I embed a YouTube video in a WordPress template page?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, youtube

I create a new template page for one of the pages on my WordPress site because all I want on on that page is some text and a YouTube video. From what I understand, WordPress doesn't accept simply embedding a YouTube video within your code, you must use the [YouTube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

But to be honest it's not very clear to me how to apply it to my current code. What can I try next?

```
<?php /* Template Name: Black Ballad Crowdfunding Subscriptions*/ ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

<head>
  <?php get_header(); ?>
  <title>Black Ballad Crowdfunding</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#more1").click(function(){
        $(".reveal1").slideToggle("slow");
        $(".video-container1").slideToggle("slow");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

  <div id="intro">
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p class="reveal1">Some more text.
      <div class="video-container1" align="center">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JfHXbPv9cUg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </p>
   <div id="more1" align="center" title="View More">
     <img src="http://www.blackballad.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/drop.png" width="20px" height="20px">
   </div>

</div>

</body>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try do_shortcode()

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

For youtube

```
echo do_shortcode( '[embed]https://www.youtube.com/user/bluehost?v=zQ-eL7zH6rQ[/embed]' );
```

Comment: I'm trying to embed the link in the raw code of the template, not the description in wordpress admin.. do you know how I can achieve that?

Comment: Yes, place that in your template between php tags wherever you would like the YouTube video to be displayed. If you need to display it in a post I believe you need to put it in a 'for' or 'while' loop. Check the WordPress docs.

Comment: I literally just put

<?php echo do_shortcode( '[embed]https://www.youtube.com/user/bluehost?v=zQ-eL7zH6rQ[/embed]' ); ?>

right at the top of my raw code & still absolutely nothing. Surely something is really wrong here. Take a look for yourself http://www.blackballad.co.uk/crowdfunding/

Comment: Well you have to replace that YouTube url with the video's url you would like to show.. But yea that should work

Comment: You may want to put that code inside the video-container1 div

Comment: Are you sure the link you posted is using a template? Or that particular template you posted in your OP?

Comment: WordPress Media Uploader allows users to upload images, documents, videos and audios creating a return reference link of the selected media files directly on the post. https://www.wpblog.com/embed-wordpress-videos-audios-images/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
global $wp_embed;
echo $wp_embed->run_shortcode( '[embed]https://vimeo.com/51589652[/embed]' );
```

Comment: For some reason @LegenJerry answer is producing an empty string for me. This is working as expected. Thanks